# incrementar campo cantidad cuando encuentre un codigo producto repetido en recyclerview

Tags: java, android, lista, arraylist, recyclerview

Incrementar el Campo  Cantidad Cuando Encuentre un código de producto Repetido en el
RecyclerView

```
**public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AdapterUsuarios adapterUsuarios;
    EditText buscarRegistro;
    Button buscar;
    Dbhelper conn;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<usuario> listaUsuario; //lista global (este tiene que ir acumulando los resultado)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buscarRegistro = findViewById(R.id.edtBuscarRegistro);
        buscar = findViewById(R.id.btnBuscarRegistro);
        conn = new Dbhelper(this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.Vista_recyclerView);
        //conn.insertarDatos("3000","Zapallo","500",1);

        listaUsuario = new ArrayList<>(); //inicializa en cero la lista global
        //RegistrosEncontrados= new ArrayList<>();

        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        adapterUsuarios=new AdapterUsuarios(listaUsuario);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsuarios);
    }
    public void BuscarRegistro(View view)
    {
        List<usuario> registrosbuscados = conn.Buscar(buscarRegistro.getText().toString());
        String codigo = registrosbuscados.get(0).getCodigo_pro();
       if(modificarProducto(codigo))
       {
         int i = 0;
         i++; 
         listaUsuario.get(3).setCantidad(i);

       }else {

           listaUsuario.addAll(registrosbuscados);
           adapterUsuarios = new AdapterUsuarios(listaUsuario);
              recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUsuarios);
       }

//limpia el texto
        buscarRegistro.setText("");


    }
```

//  metodo de comparacion de codigo producto
public boolean modificarProducto(String codigo)
{
boolean encontrado=false;
for(int contador=0;contador<listaUsuario.size();contador++)
{
//recorro recyclerview y comparo el codigo
if(listaUsuario.get(contador).getCodigo_pro().equals(codigo))
{
encontrado=true;
}else{
encontrado=false;
}
}
return encontrado;
}
}**

Answer (score 0):

Sin profundizar en el resto del código (creo que quieres que sume cada vez que se repita pero solo lo hará una vez), no estas incrementando sino asignando el valor de 1, modifica para que sume uno a la cantidad existente

```
...
  if(modificarProducto(codigo))
       {
         // recupera el valor y suma uno
         int variable = listaUsuario.get(3).getCantidad() + 1
         listaUsuario.get(3).setCantidad(variable)
       }else {
    ...
```